# How to write a dictionary into csv file, with keys having values of different length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dictionary which has multiple values for each key. The catch is that the length of values for few keys are different.

```
 {'TimeStamp': [' 5571300\r\n', ' 6074300\r\n', ' 6581300\r\n', ' 7084300\r\n'], 
 'PRESS': [' 1020.44\r\n', ' 1020.42\r\n', ' 1020.48\r\n', ' 1020.46\r\n'], 
 'GYR_X': [' -70', ' 70', ' 0', ' 0'],
 'GYR_Y': [' 630', ' 630', ' 630', ' 630'], 
 'GYR_Z': [' 210\r\n', ' 210\r\n', ' 210\r\n', ' 210\r\n'], 
 'MAG_X': [' -456', ' -450', ' -471', ' -457'], 
 'MAG_Y': [' -300', ' -307', ' -294', ' -295'], 
 'MAG_Z': [' 84\r\n', ' 84\r\n', ' 75\r\n', ' 75\r\n'], 
 'TEMP': [' +24.30\r\n', ' +24.30\r\n'], 
 'HUM': [' 71.78\r\n', ' 71.73\r\n'],
  ....}
```

How to populate this into a csv file under their respective keys?

I tried using pandas dataframe, but it requires the values to be of equal length.
`ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the length of the array in the values have to be equal & to do so, just add the `None` value until they are of equal length. They keys would have to be the column headers.

Comment: You could fill the lists with empty string or a special string like "NA" until all have the same length.

Comment: If the lengths of the values are different for some keys, how do you know which rows they correspond to? Is it just assumed they correspond to the 0..last_value, and the remainder of the rows are empty?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you want your output CSV file to look like for that example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.